# Docker + node_modules: receiving error for local dependency while trying to run Dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, node-modules

I am working on creating a docker container for a node.js microservice and am running into an issue with a local dependency from another folder.

I added the dependency to the `node_modules` folder using:

```
npm install -S ../dependency1(module name).
```

This also added an entry in the package.json as follows:

```
"dependency1": "file:../dependency1".
```

When I run the `docker-compose up -d` command, I receive an error indicating the folowing:

```
npm ERR! Could not install from "../dependency1" as it does not contain a package.json file.
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:latest

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . /usr/src/app
RUN npm install 

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
EXPOSE 3000
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
customer:
    container_name: "app_customer"
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app/
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - mongo
      - rabbitmq
```

I found articles outlining an issue with symlinks in a node_modules folder and docker and a few outlining this issue but none seem to provide a solution to this problem.  I am looking for a solution to this problem or a really good workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Docker build can't reference files outside of the build context, which is the `.` defined in the `docker-compose.yml` file.

`docker build` creates a tar bundle of all the files in a build context and sends that to the Docker daemon for the build. Anything outside the context directory doesn't exist to the build.

You could move your build context with `context: ../` to the parent directory and shuffle all the paths you reference in the `Dockerfile` to match. Just be careful not to make the build context to large as it can slow down the build process.

The other option is to publish the private npm modules to a [scope](http://blog.npmjs.org/post/116936804365/solving-npms-hard-problem-naming-packages), possible on a private npm registry that you and the build server have access to and install the dependencies normally.

Comment: Are you saying that I will have to copy all of the project folders into a parent folder that will contain the docker-compose.yml and set the context to this folder?

Comment: It doesn't have to be the same directory as the `docker-compose.yml`, the yaml just needs to reference the directory that contains everything you need access to as the `context:`

Comment: Any files you source in a `Dockerfile` need to take this new context into account.

Comment: One last thing, does that mean that the dockerfile would be considered relative where the context is set in the docker-compose.yml file?

Comment: The source parameter for `COPY` and `ADD` is relative to the build context.  I think they are the only commands that reference the context directly.